# Relation of the etymology of «epilepsy» and «cataplexy» to their meaning

Tags: medical, biology, scientific-language

I want to know the exact meaning of these 2 words (they are a medical words ... I know their scientific meaning, I need the relation of their etymology to their meaning) the prefix and the suffix of them : «epilepsy» and «cataplexy».

I tried to search many times but I couldn't get the exact meaning (lepsy: seizure ! But there are no evident relation with the meaning of the word !) and why we called them like that.

Comment: The [etymology is found at Etymonline.](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=epilepsy%2C+cataplexy) _Epilepsy_ is from Middle-French late Latin, and _cataplexy_ comes from German and Greek.

Comment: [epilepsy](https://www.etymonline.com/word/epilepsy), [cataplexy](https://www.etymonline.com/word/cataplexy)

Comment: My question was the exact meaning and it's relation to the word's meaning ... I know already each part what's mean.

Comment: Then you need to clean up the Q. It is not very clear what you are looking for. If you know the etymology and the definition you should include that in the question. You need to include basic research in the Q to abide with site standards.

Comment: I wrote clearly what I need (I even changed the title for you).

Comment: The answer is in the etymologies that Rattler and Mitch presented. Go follow the links to the Greek and PIE roots to see how the etymology relates to the scientific meaning.

Comment: How does *from Greek epilepsis "epilepsy," literally "a seizure," from epilambanein "to lay hold of, seize upon, attack," especially of diseases, but also of events, armies, etc., from epi "upon" (see epi-) + lepsis "seizure," from leps-, future stem of lambanein "take hold of, grasp"* not answer your question????

Comment: @HotLicks OMG...is that a double double question mark???? Is that allowed?? I thought Charlie said that was prohibited!?

Comment: @Rattler - I have a tremor.

Comment: The words mean exactly what they mean (which you have apparently looked up and understood). The etymology says where the parts came from. It doesn't necessarily correspond to the modern meaning of the words.

Comment: @CJDennis I know that! That's why I asked (sometimes that's related to a historical understanding of the disease)